# Managing tabIndex property of Flex fields

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

My application has multiple form and each form with multiple fields. 
 I find tabIndex property difficult to maintain. Whenever I have to add/reposition/delete a field on a given form, assigning a proper tabIndex number take maximum time.
Is there any way to maintain tabIndexes in a better way? May be while initializing a form or automating it somehow.

```
I use Flash Builder 4.6.
```

Comment: I usually avoid using `tabIndex` and try to rely on the natural tab order that is inherent in the view for just this reason ... it's very brittle to change. If you absolutely need to stray from the default tab order, you might have to create some clever initialization routine for your views, but I imagine that may also end up being a "brittle" solution as well.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I can avoid tabIndex for new pages but it is very hard to maintain existing pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better not to change the internal tab number of components. And if what you want is to focus next textfield every time you press enter key then add next code line to every textfield definition:

enter="{focusManager.getNextFocusManagerComponent().setFocus()}"

and voila! Problem solved. Using this way no matter if you delete or change components because it's very generic.

cheers